# pip install, installing packages for other python version

Tags: python, pip, conda

I am working on a GPU instance on AWS. There are some already provided Conda environments. I am using `tensorflow2_latest_p37` environment.
This environment has 2 python 3 versions .i.e `python 3.6` and `python 3.7`.

All the `preinstalled packages` are available in `python 3.7`

But whenever I am trying to do `pip install dlib` it would install it for python 3.6.
How can I install this for python 3.7?

Comment: Use `pip3.7 install dlib` instead

Comment: @rdas I tried that it says `pip3.7: command not found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the command:
`which python`.
Probably it will show you python3.6,
it means that your default python version is 3.6.

You need to search your pip3 path.

```
path/to/pip3 install dlib.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know how to use the Python 3.7 environment, you can simply use `python -m pip install ...` or more exactly:

```
command_for_python3.7 -m pip install package_name
```

If unsure, you should search for commands starting with `python` in `/bin`, `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin`. You could also have Python installations under `/opt`.

---

On Windows, the *magic word* is `py`:

```
py 3.7 -m pip install package_name
```